# batch script delete file containining certain chars

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have almost no experience in batch, but now I need a script to delete *all files that contain* certain characters in their names from a folder *and its subfolders* on Windows 64. I only did simple things in batch like

```
del "C:\TEST\TEST2\*.TXT"
```

But I have no idea how to perform the filtering I need.
Could someone help me to achieve this using batch?

**EDIT** more exactly, the question is "how to tell batch to include subfolders?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off & setlocal
set "MySearchString=X"
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /s /a-d ^| findstr /i "%MySearchString%"') do echo del "%%~i"
```

Set the variable `MySearchString` to the character or string to search and remove the `echo` command, if the output is OK.

You can also specify the `MySearchString` for the file name only:

```
@echo off & setlocal
set "MySearchString=T"
for /r %%a in (*) do for /f "delims=" %%i in ('echo("%%~na" ^| findstr /i "%MySearchString%"') do echo del "%%~fa"
```

Comment: @Maver1ck Consider to use the Damien_The_Unbeliever option for big directories wich is best improved because the Endoro script first need to process all the files with the dir command, then filter the output, then process the lines of the output, if you make that operation for example in the root directory "C:\" then you will waste x3 amount of time to process the files. Also you can use the Forfiles command.

Answer (score 7):

The `/s` switch exists on quite a few commands (including `del`)

```
del /s "C:\TEST\TEST2\*.TXT"
```

The help for `del /?` says:

```
/S            Delete specified files from all subdirectories.
```