# Bat file to delete all files with a specific string within?

Tags: batch-file

Guys I am trying to write a batch file that kills all files within a directory - basically every file will have 'status' within it

I cant just kill the files on file extension either - there is this post 
[batch script delete file containining certain chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16145169/batch-script-delete-file-containining-certain-chars)
however, this does not seem to do it

Comment: `status` within the filename or within the filecontent?

Comment: Loop through all files.  Do a `findstr` on each file.  If the `%ERRORLEVEL%` after `findstr` is 0, then delete the file.

Answer (score 2):

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (' 
    findstr /l /i /m /c:"status" "c:\somewhere\*.*"
') do echo del "%%a"
```

This uses `findstr` to list the files (`/m`) containing the literal (`/l`) `"status"` ignoring the string case (`/i`). The list is processed with a `for /f` command to execute the `del` operation for each file.

`del` commands are only echoed to console. If the output is correct, remove the `echo` command.

**edited** if the string `status` is not inside the file but in the file name, the code is reduced to

```
del "c:\somewhere\*status*"
```

Comment: sorry getting no joy with this at all - basically the only thing that should change is the "c:\somewhere\*.*" bit right? my filepath is this - C:\Users\John.Smith\Desktop\Docs\ - so the final sytax should be for /f "delims=" %a in ('findstr /l /m /c:"status" "C:\Users\John.Smith\Desktop\Docs\*.*"') do echo del "%a"

Comment: @Mr_Fish, yes, you should change the `c:\somewhere` part to match your environment. If the string to search can be uppercase, include an additional `/i` to the `findstr` to indicate it to ignore the case (i will add it to the answer). If the output to console is right (the code is not deleting anything, only echoing the commands), remove the `echo` and execute the code again to delete the files.

Comment: @Mr_Fish, remember `%a` is for command line, `%%a` for batch files as the percent sign needs to be escaped

Comment: sure - I was trying to run this via command line first - even in a batch file this wont run - so int the cmd prompt - for /f "delims=" %a in ('findstr /l /i /m /c:"status" "C:\Users\John.Smith\Desktop\Docs\*.*') do echo del "%a" - no joy, in fact its just outputting 'More?' as a responce

Comment: @Mr_Fish, You are missing some characters. The text in parenthesis should be `('findstr /l /i /m /c:"status" "C:\Users\John.Smith\Desktop\Docs\*.*"')` Not sure about the last backslash, it depends on the real location of the files, BUT the quotes MUST be included

Comment: OK nailed it! - Many thanks. Bat files are new to me and the syntax is a bit weird....been looking for resources on the subject however, these seem a bit thin on the ground - any recommendations?

Comment: sorry to be a pain - but a bit more help? How do I limit the code to just the title of the file? At the moment it is looking through the whole of the file? - Thanks again

Comment: @Mr_Fish, if by title you refer to the file name just use `del "C:\Users\John.Smith\Desktop\Docs\*status*"`, if not, what is the file title?

Comment: "C:\Users\John.Smith\Desktop\Docs\*status*" so that is the path to the folder - I just want to search the file titles, not the file content - which is what the code is doing at the moment

Comment: @Mr_Fish, by file title do you mean file name? If so, then the `del` command should do the work. If not, what is the file title? how do you get/determine the file title?

Comment: Guys thanks - I was getting a bit frustrated with this - couple of steps back and fresh eyes and it was answered in the original post - cheers for the help as ever